# POST html elemets from webpage with php

Tags: html, post

I want to store an html table in my database as single record.
I mean the following table should be posted when I click submit:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Items</td></tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to implement this?

Comment: Are you talking about putting the table in a DB as one text string? Bad idea, use an HTML form, break down the data, but it in the DB in pieces and use it how you need to later.

Comment: Go home jCloud. You're drunk.

Comment: @lampwins What about WYSIWYG HTML editors?

Comment: It can be done, just not the cleanest way of doing things, but I guess there is more than one way to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to javascript:---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit()
{
 document.getElementByID("hidTbl").value=document.getElementByID("tblToSave").innerHTML;
 document.getElementByID("form1").submit();
} 
</script>
```

Eidt  your html as follows:--

```
<form action="some.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="hidTbl" id="hidTbl" >
<input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="Post/save">
</form>

<div id="tblToSave">   
<table>
<tr><td>Items</td></tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Now get The VAlue Of Hidden input in your php

Answer (score 0):

As-is, no. Only form elements (`input`, `select`, `textarea`, etc.) that reside inside of a `form` are included in a form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this JS

```
function postwith () {
  var myForm = document.createElement("form");
  myForm.method="post" ;
  myForm.action = "PATH-TO-SERVER-SIDE-SCRIPT";

    var myInput = document.createElement("input") ;
    myInput.setAttribute("name", "table") ;
    myInput.setAttribute("value", document.getElementByID("postTable").innerHTML);
    myForm.appendChild(myInput) ;

  document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;
  myForm.submit() ;
  document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;
}
```

Then this HTML:

```
<div id="postTable">
<table>
    <tr><td>Items</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<a href="javascript:postwith()">Submit</a>
```

So just change "PATH-TO-SERVER-SIDE-SCRIPT" to the script you want to post this to.

Inside of your script simply get the value of `$_POST['table']`.